# How to revert to initial changeset in RTC 3.0.1 using CLI commands

Tags: command-line-interface, rtc

We are trying to revert to the initial change set of a component in a stream in RTC 3.0.1. The motive is to make the workspace to be having only the initial changeset.

Can anyone please suggest a way to move forward with this?

We are using CLI for that purpose . The version of RTC 3.0.1.

Is there any commands to perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a baseline or a snapshot capturing that initial changeset, that is easy enough: you can select said baseline or snapshot in your repository workspace, and deliver it again to your stream.

But if you have not, considering it is the initial changeset, that is the initial *delta*, it can be considered as a revision ([subsequent changesets are *not* like revision or commits](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/109893/get-back-to-a-specific-changeset), as they represents delta from the last changeset), the normal method is to:

- select the first baseline/snapshot you can find (the earliest one)
- [discard changets until the first one](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/176568/load-an-old-changeset-with-the-discard-command)

This is simimalr to [Work Item 86931](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert?path=internalComments[9]#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=86931), which requested (in 2010) the feature for "Providing an operation on a workspace that rolls it back to the state it had at a particular date". 6 years later, that operation is... triaged.

Comment: Every component has an initial baseline on its initial change set. You can probably find it with a command like `scm list baselines -C <component> -n "Initial Baseline"`

Comment: Also, that Work Item 86931 was fixed in 6.0.4.

Comment: @AndrewNiefer Thank you, good to know for the WI fixed. I have 6.0.3 at work (bummer). And the OP is in 3.0.3.